# Short validated measure of cognitive ability suitable for online experiment on the effect of emotion on ability test performance

Tags: cognitive-psychology, methodology, test

I am currently writing my dissertation which will examine the impact of emotion on cognitive ability. I plan to use two test groups to test my hypothesis, one which is primed to feel happy the other which is primed to feel slightly stressed.

I am looking for a question set  which I can use as a reliable test of cognitive ability - i.e. a question set that has been verified as appropriate by peer review. I am basing my experiment on an experiment carried out by [Bachkirov (2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1108/JMP-02-2013-0071). The issue I have is that I don't have the resources to use the same method and am seeking to simplify by using a questionnaire but I can't find a suitable question set. My main criteria are :

- The question set should simply measure cognitive or mental skills/abilities
- The question set should take approximately 15 minutes to complete
- The question set should be suitable to administer via survey monkey or such like
- The question set should be peer reviewed/ of have been used in a similar study which has been published .

<sub>Bachkirov, A. A. (2015). [Managerial decision making under specific emotions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1108/JMP-02-2013-0071). Journal of Managerial Psychology, 30(7), 861-874.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps this is asking a lot of an instrument? Measure "cognitive ability", unspecified, in 15 minutes, via online survey? Could you be able to specify it (perhaps "managerial ability")? Also, would you be willing to pay? The following link seems like a possible option, and their support team may provide you with the psychometrics you need: [here](http://www.revelian.com/cognitive-ability-test/). I think that generic validity may be hard to provide (for any potential instrument), as any operationalized definition of "cognitive ability" likely leaves something to be desired...

Comment: Also see: [Can a shorter IQ test be devised that provides a more approximate measure of IQ?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16925/7001)